# How to make XFCE desktop icons text transparent?

Tags: xfce

I have openSUSE 13.2 which comes with KDE as default. I want to try new desktop environments so I started XFCE. When the XFCE desktop starts the icon names on the desktop are not transparent. How to make this text transparent ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very known issue on the Internet so here are the steps:

1- Open the terminal and execute `sudo vi .gtkrc-2.0`. (You can choose your own text editor.

2- Press `a` and go to the end of the file.

3- Copy and paste the following style script

```
style "xfdesktop-icon-view" {
XfdesktopIconView::label-alpha = 0
XfdesktopIconView::selected-label-alpha = 170

base[NORMAL] = "#cccccc"
base[SELECTED] = "#cccccc"
base[ACTIVE] = "#cccccc"

fg[NORMAL] = "#ffffff"
fg[SELECTED] = "#000000"
fg[ACTIVE] = "#000000"
}
widget_class "*XfdesktopIconView*" style "xfdesktop-icon-view"
```

4- Press `Esc` and then `:wq` to save the file.

[Source](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/enable-transparent-label-text-background-on-the-xfce-desktop/)

P.S.: If you copied the style from the website it won't work. It appears that the double quotation mark is not THE quotation mark so I changed them all and posted it here.

Comment: sudo is actually a bad idea, it is unneeded, and they are forever going to have to use it to change stuff in the future if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 3):

In the above example, "sudo" is not needed, as the file is being created inside the user's home directory. i.e.

```
vi .gtkrc-2.0
```

or

```
nano .gtkrc-2.0
```

is enough.

Then add these, save and quit:

```
style "xfdesktop-icon-view" {
XfdesktopIconView::label-alpha = 0
XfdesktopIconView::selected-label-alpha = 170

base[NORMAL] = "#cccccc"
base[SELECTED] = "#cccccc"
base[ACTIVE] = "#cccccc"

fg[NORMAL] = "#ffffff"
fg[SELECTED] = "#000000"
fg[ACTIVE] = "#000000"
}
widget_class "*XfdesktopIconView*" style "xfdesktop-icon-view"
```

logout xfce and log back in.